# Selected processor does not support `dmb ish' in ARM mode

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, embedded, embedded-linux

I am building an embedded linux distro on a Beaglebone Black (AM335x chip Cortex-A8 Arm-v7 Instruction set) using crosstool-NG, U-Boot, Kernel (5.5.5) and buildroot. When compiling the kernel I am getting this error message:

```
/tmp/ccxFZlyN.s: Assembler messages:                                                                                                                                                                
/tmp/ccxFZlyN.s:39: Error: selected processor does not support `isb ' in ARM mode                                                                                                                   
/tmp/ccxFZlyN.s:90: Error: selected processor does not support `isb ' in ARM mode                                                                                                                   
/tmp/ccxFZlyN.s:371: Error: selected processor does not support `isb ' in ARM mode                                                                                                                  
scripts/Makefile.build:265: recipe for target 'arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.o' failed                                                                                                                     
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/vfp/vfpmodule.o] Error 1                                                                                                                                                     
Makefile:1693: recipe for target 'arch/arm/vfp' failed                                                                                                                                              
make: *** [arch/arm/vfp] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      init/do_mounts_rd.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:275: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb ish' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:278: Error: architectural extension `mp' is not allowed for the current base architecture
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:279: Error: selected processor does not support `pldw [r3]' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:282: Error: selected processor does not support `pld [r3]' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:288: Error: selected processor does not support `ldrex r2,[r3]' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:290: Error: selected processor does not support `strex r1,r2,[r3]' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccg2MH8t.s:295: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb ish' in ARM mode
scripts/Makefile.build:265: recipe for target 'init/do_mounts.o' failed
make[1]: *** [init/do_mounts.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/ccFNavBu.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccFNavBu.s:1990: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccFNavBu.s:2123: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsid i' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccFNavBu.s:2204: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsie i' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccFNavBu.s:2426: Error: selected processor does not support `cpsie i' in ARM mode
scripts/Makefile.build:265: recipe for target 'init/main.o' failed
```

Here is my toolchain:

```
arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/john/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/libexec/gcc/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: /home/john/Documents/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/src/gcc/configure --build=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/home/john/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf --with-sysroot=/home/john/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-cpu=cortex-a8 --with-float=hard --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG 1.24.0.105_5659366' --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libmpx --with-gmp=/home/john/Documents/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/buildtools --with-mpfr=/home/john/Documents/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/buildtools --with-mpc=/home/john/Documents/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/buildtools --with-isl=/home/john/Documents/crosstool-ng/.build/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/buildtools --enable-lto --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --enable-plugin --enable-gold --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/john/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot --enable-long-long
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.105_5659366)
```

Here is my full bootlog:

```
U-Boot 2020.04 (Jun 11 2020 - 15:14:20 +0100)                                                                                                                                                       

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1                                                                                                                                                                            
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black                                                                                                                                                                   
DRAM:  512 MiB                                                                                                                                                                                      
WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout)                                                                                                                                                         
NAND:  0 MiB                                                                                                                                                                                        
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1                                                                                                                                                               
Loading Environment from FAT... OK                                                                                                                                                                  
Net:   eth0: ethernet@4a100000                                                                                                                                                                      
Warning: usb_ether MAC addresses don't match:                                                                                                                                                       
Address in ROM is          de:ad:be:ef:00:01                                                                                                                                                        
Address in environment is  0c:ae:7d:0c:4f:f4                                                                                                                                                        
, eth1: usb_ether                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0                                                                                                                                                                    
switch to partitions #0, OK                                                                                                                                                                         
mmc0 is current device                                                                                                                                                                              
SD/MMC found on device 0                                                                                                                                                                            
475 bytes read in 3 ms (154.3 KiB/s)                                                                                                                                                                
Loaded env from uEnv.txt                                                                                                                                                                            
Importing environment from mmc0 ...                                                                                                                                                                 
Running uenvcmd ...                                                                                                                                                                                 
7995904 bytes read in 515 ms (14.8 MiB/s)                                                                                                                                                           
33325 bytes read in 6 ms (5.3 MiB/s)                                                                                                                                                                
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 80f80000                                                                                                                                                           
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80f80000                                                                                                                                                         
   Loading Device Tree to 8fff4000, end 8ffff22c ... OK                                                                                                                                             

Starting kernel ...                                                                                                                                                                                 

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0                                                                                                                                                    
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.5.5-john (john@homepc) (gcc version 9.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.105_5659366)) #1 SMP Thu Jun 11 13:29:44 BST 2020                                              
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc082] revision 2 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d                                                                                                                      
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache                                                                                                             
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black                                                                                                                                   
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback                                                                                                                                                  
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:                                                                                                                                                
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.                                                                                                                                                                 
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 64 MiB at 0x9b800000                                                                                                                                                   
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.                                                                                                                                                 
[    0.000000] AM335X ES2.1 (sgx neon)                                                                                                                                                              
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 19 pages/cpu s48908 r8192 d20724 u77824                                                                                                                             
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129540                                                                                                                        
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyO0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4                                                                                                        
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 432996K/522240K available (11264K kernel code, 1131K rwdata, 4240K rodata, 1024K init, 306K bss, 23708K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=16 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] IRQ: Found an INTC at 0x(ptrval) (revision 5.0) with 128 interrupts
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x314/0x4c0 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] OMAP clockevent source: timer2 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.000015] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000034] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000044] OMAP clocksource: timer1 at 24000000 Hz
[    0.001702] timer_probe: no matching timers found
[    0.001897] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001923] WARNING: Your 'console=ttyO0' has been replaced by 'ttyS0'
[    0.001930] This ensures that you still see kernel messages. Please
[    0.001935] update your kernel commandline.
[    0.001974] Calibrating delay loop... 996.14 BogoMIPS (lpj=4980736)
[    0.089197] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.089352] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.089367] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.090125] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.090197] CPU0: Spectre v2: using BPIALL workaround
[    0.090576] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket -1, mpidr 0
[    0.091191] Setting up static identity map for 0x80300000 - 0x803000ac
[    0.091613] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.094062] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.094229] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.094242] smp: Brought up 1 node, 1 CPU
[    0.094252] SMP: Total of 1 processors activated (996.14 BogoMIPS).
[    0.094259] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.094791] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.101284] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 3
[    0.101581] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.101610] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.105563] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.107106] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.107372] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.107846] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.110311] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.132055] l4_wkup_cm:clk:0010:0: failed to disable
[    0.134222] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.140353] platform 44e07000.gpio: Cannot lookup hwmod 'gpio1'
[    0.140559] omap_gpio 44e07000.gpio: Could not get gpio dbck. Disable debounce
[    0.140581] omap_gpio 44e07000.gpio: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    0.141005] OMAP GPIO hardware version 0.1
[    0.141300] platform 4804c000.gpio: Cannot lookup hwmod 'gpio2'
[    0.141513] omap_gpio 4804c000.gpio: Could not get gpio dbck. Disable debounce
[    0.141531] omap_gpio 4804c000.gpio: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    0.142104] platform 481ac000.gpio: Cannot lookup hwmod 'gpio3'
[    0.142308] omap_gpio 481ac000.gpio: Could not get gpio dbck. Disable debounce
[    0.142326] omap_gpio 481ac000.gpio: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    0.142870] platform 481ae000.gpio: Cannot lookup hwmod 'gpio4'
[    0.143060] omap_gpio 481ae000.gpio: Could not get gpio dbck. Disable debounce
[    0.143075] omap_gpio 481ae000.gpio: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    0.143603] platform 44e09000.serial: Cannot lookup hwmod 'uart1'
[    0.144022] platform 44e0b000.i2c: Cannot lookup hwmod 'i2c1'
[    0.144318] platform 4819c000.i2c: Cannot lookup hwmod 'i2c3'
[    0.144581] platform 48060000.mmc: Cannot lookup hwmod 'mmc1'
[    0.144843] platform 481d8000.mmc: Cannot lookup hwmod 'mmc2'
[    0.145407] platform 44e35000.wdt: Cannot lookup hwmod 'wd_timer2'
[    0.145706] platform 480c8000.mailbox: Cannot lookup hwmod 'mailbox'
[    0.147736] platform 47400000.usb: Cannot lookup hwmod 'usb_otg_hs'
[    0.148253] platform 4a100000.ethernet: Cannot lookup hwmod 'cpgmac0'
[    0.150389] platform 48310000.rng: Cannot lookup hwmod 'rng'
[    0.151017] No ATAGs?
[    0.151024] hw-breakpoint: debug architecture 0x4 unsupported.
[    0.153962] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.173976] edma 49000000.edma: TI EDMA DMA engine driver
[    0.177034] iommu: Default domain type: Translated
[    0.177379] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.178274] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.178877] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.178928] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.178986] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.180177] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.180191] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.180213] PTP clock support registered
[    0.180374] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.183425] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1
[    0.760718] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.761388] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    0.761416] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.761458] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.761517] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.761633] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.761659] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.761799] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.762495] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.762508] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.762515] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.762521] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.762535] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.763813] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a8 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.765384] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.765727] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=17 bucket_order=0
[    0.771682] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.772630] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.772677] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.772685] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.772730] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
[    0.773274] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.773285] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.773342] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 248)
[    0.773353] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.773360] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.776728] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins, size 568
[    0.832881] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 5 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.835861] omap8250 44e09000.serial: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    0.836680] 44e09000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x44e09000 (irq = 30, base_baud = 3000000) is a 8250
[    1.608905] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.614361] SuperH (H)SCI(F) driver initialized
[    1.619312] msm_serial: driver initialized
[    1.623670] STMicroelectronics ASC driver initialized
[    1.629822] STM32 USART driver initialized
[    1.634758] omap_rng 48310000.rng: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    1.643478] omap_rng 48310000.rng: Failed to runtime_get device: -19
[    1.649861] omap_rng 48310000.rng: initialization failed.
[    1.668610] brd: module loaded
[    1.679286] loop: module loaded
[    1.688192] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.693549] CAN device driver interface
[    1.698157] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.704072] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.725075] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    1.734257] pegasus: v0.9.3 (2013/04/25), Pegasus/Pegasus II USB Ethernet driver
[    1.741748] usbcore: registered new interface driver pegasus
[    1.747522] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[    1.752974] usbcore: registered new interface driver ax88179_178a
[    1.759153] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    1.765082] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc75xx
[    1.770893] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.776715] usbcore: registered new interface driver net1080
[    1.782424] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[    1.788416] usbcore: registered new interface driver zaurus
[    1.794079] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    1.801423] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.808049] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.812558] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.818008] ehci-st: EHCI STMicroelectronics driver
[    1.823011] tegra-ehci: Tegra EHCI driver
[    1.827199] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.833472] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.837984] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    1.843427] ohci-st: OHCI STMicroelectronics driver
[    1.848834] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.857926] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.867206] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.873499] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.878477] omap_gpio 44e07000.gpio: Could not set line 6 debounce to 200000 microseconds (-524)
[    1.887371] omap_hsmmc 48060000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    1.892220] omap_hsmmc: probe of 48060000.mmc failed with error -2
[    1.898768] omap_hsmmc: probe of 481d8000.mmc failed with error -2
[    1.905886] Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver
[    1.912404] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.920105] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.927530] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.933134] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.938468] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.945737] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.951373] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.955262] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    1.961939] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.966492] can: controller area network core (rev 20170425 abi 9)
[    1.972784] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    1.977277] can: raw protocol (rev 20170425)
[    1.981566] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20170425 t)
[    1.987274] can: netlink gateway (rev 20190810) max_hops=1
[    1.993306] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.997802] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    2.002106] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    2.007212] omap_voltage_late_init: Voltage driver support not added
[    2.014818] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.034806] omap_i2c 44e0b000.i2c: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    2.045484] omap_i2c 4819c000.i2c: _od_fail_runtime_resume: FIXME: missing hwmod/omap_dev info
[    2.056304] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    2.066764] l4_per_cm:clk:0008:0: failed to disable
[    2.076823] l4_wkup_cm:clk:00d0:0: failed to disable
[    2.086878] l4_wkup_cm:clk:00b0:0: failed to disable
[    2.093215] VFS: Cannot open root device "mmcblk0p2" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[    2.101092] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    2.109521] 0100           65536 ram0
[    2.109524]  (driver?)
[    2.115670] 0101           65536 ram1
[    2.115672]  (driver?)
[    2.121797] 0102           65536 ram2
[    2.121799]  (driver?)
[    2.127940] 0103           65536 ram3
[    2.127942]  (driver?)
[    2.134083] 0104           65536 ram4
[    2.134085]  (driver?)
[    2.140212] 0105           65536 ram5
[    2.140214]  (driver?)
[    2.146353] 0106           65536 ram6
[    2.146355]  (driver?)
[    2.152481] 0107           65536 ram7
[    2.152483]  (driver?)
[    2.158622] 0108           65536 ram8
[    2.158624]  (driver?)
[    2.164764] 0109           65536 ram9
[    2.164766]  (driver?)
[    2.170892] 010a           65536 ram10
[    2.170894]  (driver?)
[    2.177121] 010b           65536 ram11
[    2.177123]  (driver?)
[    2.183335] 010c           65536 ram12
[    2.177121] 010b           65536 ram11
[    2.177123]  (driver?)
[    2.183335] 010c           65536 ram12
[    2.183337]  (driver?)
[    2.189566] 010d           65536 ram13
[    2.189568]  (driver?)
[    2.195796] 010e           65536 ram14
[    2.195798]  (driver?)
[    2.202010] 010f           65536 ram15
[    2.202012]  (driver?)
[    2.208247] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    2.216554] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.5.5-john #1
[    2.223368] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
[    2.229528] [<c03124e0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c030c6dc>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[    2.237319] [<c030c6dc>] (show_stack) from [<c0daa3e8>] (dump_stack+0xbc/0xd0)
[    2.244585] [<c0daa3e8>] (dump_stack) from [<c0338e60>] (panic+0x110/0x328)
[    2.251586] [<c0338e60>] (panic) from [<c13014d8>] (mount_block_root+0x1ac/0x240)
[    2.259105] [<c13014d8>] (mount_block_root) from [<c13017d8>] (mount_root+0x124/0x148)
[    2.267057] [<c13017d8>] (mount_root) from [<c130197c>] (prepare_namespace+0x180/0x1bc)
[    2.275100] [<c130197c>] (prepare_namespace) from [<c0dc1e50>] (kernel_init+0x8/0x110)
[    2.283055] [<c0dc1e50>] (kernel_init) from [<c03010e8>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c)
[    2.290655] Exception stack(0xdb0b1fb0 to 0xdb0b1ff8)
[    2.295728] 1fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    2.303941] 1fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    2.312152] 1fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[    2.318812] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

So it looks like the device can read partition one fine since its reading uEnv.txt but it can't mount or read partition two of the sd card

Comment: Thanks I checked it out the Cortx-A8 has two coprocessors: vfpv3 or neon. I specified neon and it built succesfully

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify a specific FPU? IIRC for the BBB you need to select `neon` for the `Use specific FPU option`, else you get an error like this.

Also refer to https://tgarc.github.io/2015/03/08/building-a-linaro-cross-compiler-toolchain-with-cross-ng/

Comment: Thanks I changed it to neon and the kernel successfully builds however after I flashed the rootfs to the sd card the kernel now hangs: **Starting kernel ...** and I am getting a message on boot saying: ** Unknown command 'earlyprintk' - try help **. I am guessing it is something to do with my console tty?

Comment: Could also be your devicetree. Could you post your kernel command line and u-boot configuration?

Comment: Here is my uEnv.txt:

`console=ttyS0,115200
ethaddr=02:f8:7e:a6:fc:e1
ipaddr=192.168.1.1
serverip=192.168.1.10
bootfile=zImage
fdtfile=am335x-boneblack.dtb
loadaddr=0x80007fc0
fdtaddr=0x80F80000
loadfdt=fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}
loaduimage=fatload mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} ${bootfile}
fdtboot=run bootargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
bootargs=earlyprintk console=${console} root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4
uenvcmd=mmc rescan; run loaduimage; run loadfdt; run fdtboot;
`

Comment: Isn't your console supposed to be `ttyO0` for the AM335x?

Comment: No idea but I'll try it out. How do you know that information? I can't seem to find that out in the technical manual.

Comment: New error: **[    2.319038] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---**. Kernel cant mount the root filesystem. My method is using: **sudo dd if=buildroot/output/images/rootfs.ext4 of=/dev/sdc2**. Any other suggestions?

Comment: **VFS: Cannot open root device "mmcblk0p2" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6**

Comment: Can you post the full boot log? Does it detect your mmc?

Comment: the full boot log is now inserted into the edited post. Yeah it can read mmc fine since theres a uEnv.txt on the first partition of the sd card but it cant mount or read the second partition. I flashed the rootfs onto the sd card using **sudo dd if=buildroot/output/images/rootfs.ext4 of=/dev/sdb2**

Comment: Well yeah, but your uEnv.txt and the kernel are loaded by u-boot, not the kernel. Seems like the kernel can't initialize the MMC:
`[    1.892220] omap_hsmmc: probe of 48060000.mmc failed with error -2
[    1.898768] omap_hsmmc: probe of 481d8000.mmc failed with error -2` and that probably suggests issues with the device tree.

Comment: Strange as im going through **https://elinux.org/Building_for_BeagleBone** tutorial. I'll play around with it cheers

Comment: Got it working! The issue was that I was copying the dtb from the U-boot directory instead of the kernel directory. I dont know what the difference is but it now boots up fine! Thanks for your help Alexander